# Why is mySQL very slow after importing a lot of data?

Tags: mysql, php, windows-7

I have been developing with PHP and mySQL. The report I use (TCPDF) is running well and doesn't have any problems. But after I try to import a lot of data, the report is not run and is blank. I Can't generate to PDF and mySQL is very slow

I have been optimizing my tables and not changed anything.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should enable MySQL slow query logging (more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html)). Also could you please post your `my.cnf` for review. Most probably you should tune MyISAM or InnoDB buffer size depending on what storage engine you use. You can use [mysqlreport](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreport) to get a comprehensive report on buffers usage/effectivenes and a bunch of other important parameters.